# How to calculate scores without using enumerate

Tags: python

I have designed this python card game, I'm wondering if there is a better way to calculated each player scores without using the enumerate option. I'm very new to Coding/Python only few weeks. Only know the bare basics.My friend was helped me do this.

```
def select_winner(players_scores, player_names):
    max = 0
    winner = ''
    print('The game scores are:')

    for index, score in enumerate(players_scores):
        current_player = player_names[index]
        print(current_player, "=", score)
        if score > max:
            max = score
            winner = current_player

    print("The winner is:", winner)
```

Is there a simpler way to do this, that will help me understand it better/easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) if you really just don't want to use enumerate:

```
for current_player, score in zip(player_names, player_scores):
    print(current_player)
    print(score)
    <etc>
```

zip lets you loop over two lists at once in the same order.

But yea you can also just use Python's max function to find the maximum score.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to reduce the number of lines if you only want to find the best score would be to the index() and max() methods included in the standard python library. An edge case you have to consider is what happens if there two people with the same max score.

```
def select_winner(players_scores, player_names):
    index_of_max = players_scores.index(max(players_scores))
    print('The winner is:', players_names[index_of_max], 
          'with a score of', players_scores[index_of_max])
```

If you absolutely want to list all the scores too, you should use the handy zip() function that lets you access multiple iterables at once. For example:

```
list1 = (1, 2, 3)
list2 = ('a', 'b', 'c')
for a, b in zip(list1, list2):
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through all the players, you can create a dictionary with the player name as the key and their score as the value. Because we are in the endgame now, speed probably doesn't matter too much.

Here's the code:

```py
def select_winner(players_scores, player_names):
    print('The game scores are:')

    # This creates the dictionary of the players
    players = dict(zip(player_names, player_scores))

    # order based on the score
    ordered = sorted(players.items(), key=lambda player: player[1])

    # last one in the sorted list (largest score)
    winner_name, winner_score = ordered[-1]

    print(
        "The winner is:", winner_name,
        "with an astounding", winner_score, "points!",
    )
```

The `players` will be something like:

```
{
    "Gee": 10,
    "Vye": 40,
    "Tor": 20,
    "Kat": 30,
}
```

Getting a dictionary's `.items()` returns a bunch of 2-tuples like `("Gee", 10)`. (In reality they return an iterator but that's too advanced for now.)

The `ordered` list will be like:

```
[
    ("Gee", 10),
    ("Tor", 20),
    ("Kat", 30),
    ("Vye", 40),
]
```

By taking the final tuple, `("Vye", 40)`, we get the winner's name and score. Putting `winner_name, winner_score = ("Vye", 40)` is the same as `winner_name = ("Vye", 40)[0]; winner_score = ("Vye", 40)[1]`.

Hope you understand all of this. If not, just comment the question. Else, code on!